# Flatten inner lists within nested list

Tags: python, list

I have sublists that contain internal nested lists per each sublist and I'd like to only flatten the internal nested list, so its just part of the sublist.

The list goes,

```
A=[[[[a ,b], [e ,f]], [e, g]],
   [[[d, r], [d, g]], [l, m]],
   [[[g, d], [e, r]], [g, t]]]
```

I'd like to flatten the nested list that appears in the first position of each sublist in A so the output looks like this,

```
A= [[[a ,b], [e ,f], [e, g]],
    [[d, r], [d, g], [l, m]],
    [[g, d], [e, r], [g, t]]]
```

Im not sure what code to use to do this, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Comment: I really enjoyed your recent questions, but would it be possible to format your list as strings? because we all had to manually do it

Comment: Oh yes sorry about that, Ill keep that in mind for next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension with [unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) to flatten that first inner list:

```
A[:] = [[*i, j] for i,j in A]
```

For pythons older than 3.0:

```
[i+[j] for i,j in A]
```

---

```
print(A)

[[['a', 'b'], ['e', 'f'], ['e', 'g']],
 [['d', 'r'], ['d', 'g'], ['l', 'm']],
 [['g', 'd'], ['e', 'r'], ['g', 't']]]
```

Comment: Hey, so for some reason Im getting an invalid syntax error. Im working in python 2 maybe thats why?

Comment: Updated @asiv - yes that's the reason

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
B = [[*el[0], el[1]] for el in A]
print(B)
```

Output:

```
[[['a', 'b'], ['e', 'f'], ['e', 'g']],
 [['d', 'r'], ['d', 'g'], ['l', 'm']],
 [['g', 'd'], ['e', 'r'], ['g', 't']]]
```

Alternatively, for Python 2 (the star `*` operator does not behave in the same way here):

```
B = list(map(lambda x: [x[0][0], x[0][1], x[1]], A))
```

You can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYy7DsMgDEV3vuJuBomh6VgpQ/IbiIGINo0EKaIM6ddTnD4tD/dx7PQo19t6rHXoTRtyBA2ayGoYOpOmC9mPBs1sBABGPSf5Rfpv20xgE//RmRNPv0f5je5FacaKET3Cci8yuiSDi5N32E4wmznYthq76JpoquPzQSmR8rIWOapanw)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is as simple as it gets:

```
[*map(lambda x: x[0] + [x[1]], A)]
```

```
[[['a', 'b'], ['e', 'f'], ['e', 'g']],
 [['d', 'r'], ['d', 'g'], ['l', 'm']],
 [['g', 'd'], ['e', 'r'], ['g', 't']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A little verbose but works:

```
import itertools

container = [list(itertools.chain(i[0] + [i[1]])) for i in A]

print(container)
```

Result:

```
[[['a', 'b'], ['e', 'f'], ['e', 'g']], 
 [['d', 'r'], ['d', 'g'], ['l', 'm']], 
 [['g', 'd'], ['e', 'r'], ['g', 't']]]
```